# DateTime format issue from sql server to C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, datetime

I am having an issue with DateTime formats when I `ParseExact` a `SqlDataReader` string from SQL Server into a DateTime in c#.

The format in the DB is : `yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.fff`

When I write in the console the result of the `DataReader`, I get a new format which is : `dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss`

I tried to `ParseExact` with both format.

The issue I have is that when the "Time" part is null (ex : `00:00:00.000`) I haven't got any issue it parses and I can store it etc... But when I've got any value in this "Time" part (ex : `08:30:25.125`) it tells me the string is not recognized as a valid `DateTime` format.

Comment: Can you share the code and tell what exact issue you are facing?

Comment: Please provide input data sample and desirable result.